# Making block diagram of an op-amp configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, non-inverting

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have to make the block diagram of the above configuration. Supposing the input capacitance of op-amp Cin, I've drawn this:

[image]

A is the open loop transfer function of the OPA.

B is the voltage divider between C1,C2//R and Cin. V(-)=Vout*B

C is the voltage divider between C1,Cin and C2//R. V(-)=Vin*C

Should it be good?

Comment: Are you forgetting that the inverting input in this configuration is a virtual ground and so is at 0 V?

Comment: The "danger" with what you're doing here is that the circuit uses either current or voltage as a **signal** and that the block diagram does not. In a block diagram the signal is just a number, it has no unit. I have a **problem** with your circuit as usually for this configuration, C1 will have a large value making it a short for AC signals. This effectively eliminates the influence of the feedback (R and C2) for AC. For DC the resistor is needed to set the DC operating point though. Smells like a teacher who doesn't really understand opamp circuits :-(

Comment: At first, the block diagram - formally spoken - is correct. However, it is very uncommon to take Cin into consideration. More than that, there is sign error. We have negative feedback and - consequently - there is a minus sign at the summing junction. That is correct. If the block "A" is considered as positive, the block "C" must be negative because the overall gain is negative for this inverting opamp application.

Answer (score 1):

Redrawing your schematic with a few node names added: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frhhKF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The op-amp amplifies the voltage difference between its terminals by its open loop gain \$A_\text{ol}\$ (very large usually > 10e6). So to draw the block diagram, we need an expression for \$V_\text{ref}\$ and \$V_a\$.

The positive terminal is grounded, so \$V_\text{ref} = 0\$. To find \$V_a\$ one node equation is enough.

$$(V_a-V_\text{in})sC_1 + (V_a-V_o)sC_2+\frac{V_a-V_o}{R_1} = 0 $$

Solving this yields

$$V_a = V_\text{in} \bigg( \frac{sC_1R_1}{sC_1R_1 + sC_2R_1 + 1} \bigg) + V_o \bigg( \frac{sC_2R_1 + 1}{sC_1R_1 + sC_2R_1 + 1} \bigg) $$

In the block diagram \$V_\text{in}\$ is considered a disturbance. It is now trivial to draw the diagram: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the input side( without the consideration of C<sub>in</sub>),

```
I1(s)=Vin(s)*sC1 ;
```

On the output side,

```
       I2(s)=Vout(s) ( sC2 + 1/R) ;
i.e.,  I2(s)=Vout(s) (sRC2 + 1)/R ;
```

Since,

```
I1(s)=I2(s)
```

So,

```
Vout(s)/Vin(s) = sRC1/(1 + sRC2) ;
```

Comparing with Closed loop transfer function

```
Gain= G(s)/(1+G(s)H(s))  ;

G(s) = sRC1 ; H(s)= C2/C1 ;
```